Docker Swarm: Access to PostgreSQL container through VPN container from personal laptop
I have a server with Docker Swarm cluster initiated.
docker-compose.yaml:
version: "3.9"

services:
  postgres:
    image: 'postgres:16.2'
    volumes:
      - "postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=mydb
      - POSTGRES_USER=myuser
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=secret
    deploy:
      replicas: 1

  openvpn:
    image: kylemanna/openvpn
    cap_add:
      - NET_ADMIN
    environment:
      - OVPN_PORT=1194
    volumes:
      - "vpn:/etc/openvpn"
    ports:
      - published: 1194
        target: 1194
        protocol: udp
    deploy:
      replicas: 1

volumes:
  postgres:
  vpn:

networks:
  default:
    driver: overlay
    attachable: true

openvpn.conf:
server 192.168.255.0 255.255.255.0
verb 3
key /etc/openvpn/pki/private/<ip>.key
ca /etc/openvpn/pki/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/pki/issued/<ip>.crt
dh /etc/openvpn/pki/dh.pem
tls-auth /etc/openvpn/pki/ta.key
key-direction 0
persist-key
persist-tun

proto udp
# Rely on Docker to do port mapping, internally always 1194
port 1194
dev tun0
status /tmp/openvpn-status.log

user nobody
group nogroup
comp-lzo no

### Route Configurations Below
route 192.168.254.0 255.255.255.0
route 10.0.0.0 255.0.0.0

### Push Configurations Below
push "block-outside-dns"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"
push "route 10.0.0.0 255.0.0.0"
push "redirect-gateway def1"

keepalive 10 120

Description:
All I want is to setup secure access to PostgreSQL through VPN from my laptop with psql or DataGrip like this (second option is better):
psql -U myuser -d mydb -h 10.0.2.19 -p 5432 (1)
or 
psql -U myuser -d mydb -h postgres -p 5432 (2)

As we can see in docker-compose.yaml both of containers are in the same default network. I tried to ping postgres from openvpn and it works as expected:
/ # hostname
df3a74744fe5
/ # ping postgres
PING postgres (10.0.2.19): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 10.0.2.19: seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.098 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.2.19: seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.157 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.2.19: seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.143 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.2.19: seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.192 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.2.19: seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.161 ms

Also, I can successfully connect to openvpn container from Tunnelblick on my laptop. But I can't reach postgres container.
As I know, Docker Swarm default subnet is 10.0.0.0/8 and I tried to add appropriate configuration to openvpn.conf but it doesn't help.
I suspect that when I'm connecting to openvpn and trying to reach postgres container - for him I act from VPN subnet 192.168.254.0/24.
Questions:

Where is a problem and how to connect to postgres container through VPN?
Is it possible to use Docker DNS Resolver on 127.0.0.1 for accessing postgres?

